# Microstrategy - Unable to calculate the difference between two dates related by fact table

Tags: microstrategy

We are trying to calculate the difference between two dates.

The scenario is the following.

```
3 Dimensions:
DIM_DATE
DIM_RELEASE_DATE (Alias of DIM_DATE)
DIM_PRODUCT

1 Fact table:
FT_SALES

FT_SALES relates to DIM_DATE and DIM_PRODUCT.
DIM_RELEASE_DATE relates to DIM_PRODUCT
```

Currently the DIM_DATE.DATE and DIM_RELEASE_DATE.DATE are attributes.

We are trying to calculate the Days Between DIM_RELEASE_DATE.DATE and DIM_DATE.DATE
ie. DaysBetween(DIM_RELEASE_DATE.DATE@ID,DIM_DATE.DATE@ID)

My understanding is that I cannot create a compound attribute using dimension columns from two tables. 
I tried creating facts for each date field and performing the DaysBetween in a metric. This unfortunately results in a CROSS JOIN which is huge.

How can i go about calculating the difference between two attributes (or facts) that are related through a fact table while avoiding a cross join ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a fact defined as

```
FT_SALES.DATE - FT_SALES.RELEASE_DATE
```

Then you can use a metric on top of it and the metric will always return you the differences between the two columns from your fact table.